# How to get middle element of array if we don't know size of array

Tags: arrays

I was asked question in interview ,write an algorithm to find middle element of array when you don't know size of array.

Comment: run 2 pointers, 1 moves 1 step and the other moves 2 steps. when the the 2nd reaches the end, your first pointer is pointing at the middle element

Comment: Was it the full question? Can you choose a specific language?

Comment: Do you mean middle element as in index or value?

Comment: @VishalSharma, how will we know that 2nd pointer has reached the end?

Comment: @HarshitGangwar depends on the language. For instance if it’s js, i can just check if arr[i] is present or not. There will be more constraints though. Like array can hold values like null and undefined in js. In that case it’ll be a little tough. Interviewers ask these vague questions and expect candidates to understand those constraints and question such possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Is it cheating to count the elements yourself?

Java:

```
Object [] mysteriousArray = getMysteriousArray();
int count = 0;
for (Object value: mysteriousArray) {
    count++;
}
Object middle = mysteriousArray[count/2];
```

Comment: @Brain I think that would be easiest  approach for unknown length of array ,that is only option  .

Comment: @DivyKumar If you like it, how about accepting it :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Java:

```
int[] array = new int[/*mystery value*/];
```

The statement `array[(int)((array.length-1)/2)]` will return the middle value, rounding down.